# Comparing each pixel from a given image to another pixel from another image with color

Tags: opencv, image-processing

Can I compare a pixel from the original image to another same coordinate pixel from a colored image to check what is the color of the pixel from the colored image to the original image? Is there a way to do that?

Comment: How can I check the pixel value? Is checking the pixel value possible? For example I have an Binary Image with color how do I check the pixel value?

Comment: on SO there are some questions on how to access a openaCV Mat element (= a pixel)

Answer (score 0):

You can take the absolute difference between them. The result will be the difference of each pixel.

```
cv::Mat first,second,result;
//first= some image
//second =other image
cv::absdiff(first,second,result);
```

**EDIT:**

By the previous step, you have got the difference map. You can simply now do this:

```
auto some_pixle_difference=result.at<vec3b>(cv::Point(x,y));
```

`some_pixle_difference` will contain the differences between `pixel x,y` from both images.

Comment: Helawi Sorry for the late reply, may i ask why should i get the difference of each pixel? I just need to compare the pixel from one image to another image.

Comment: @jon edited. feel free to ask about further explanation

Comment: i see, so it just check between the 2 images if there is a difference in their pixel value

Comment: may i ask, is there a way to check if one of the image is with a RGB color and the other was is in grayscale?

Comment: see this http://answers.opencv.org/question/36288/how-to-know-grayscale-or-color-img-loaded/

Comment: oh wait it seems my question lacks detailes, what i really want to ask is to know what color it hold in a colored image using a certain coordinate(x,y) from a grayscale image